# Is it possible to get the location/position of the mouse cursor on document load event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Just wondering if its possible to get the x/y location of the mouse from the `onload` event of the document (before any `mousemove` events)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer: no

long answer: yes. the onload event doesn't provide info on the mouse position, however you can set a variable when onload has fired, and use the onmousemove event on the document to get the mouseposition as soon as the mouse moves after the documents loads (after the variable has been set). Not what you wanted, though.

Comment: Didn't think it was possible, but I thought perhaps someone knew a hack.  Thanks for verifying.

Comment: Is there a reason why this information isn't exposed? It would also be nice to get mouse information in the onfocus event.

Comment: @nornagon, probably because it isn't particularly relevant. There are other ways to focus an element (Using the tab key or a touch screen,  for example). Mouse data is only available in mouse-related events like onmousemove or onmouseover. That said, you could listen to the onclick event for focus (but onclick does not guarantee focus). Better yet, use both event handlers and use a temporary, element specific storage mechanism (like html5 data) to keep track of the events.

Comment: That doesn't help for when the user alt-tabs away, moves the mouse, and alt-tabs back. Use case: I want the space key to act like a mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetValues() {
  var IE = document.all?true:false;
  if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
  getMouseXY();
  var mX = 0;
  var mY = 0;
  function getMouseXY(e) {
    if (IE) {
      mX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
      mY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }
    else {
      mX = e.pageX;
      mY = e.pageY;
    }  

    var s = 'X=' + mX +  ' Y=' + mY ;
    document.getElementById('divCoord').innerHTML = s;
    return true;
  }
}
</script></head>
<body onload=SetValues()>
<div id="divCoord"></div>
</body></html>
```